# How to replicate Android app sheet in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

So, I really want to replicate the Android app list sheet (of stock Android) in Flutter, but so far, I haven't had much success...

I haven't found yet a sheet that has this exactly behaviour (with the user needing to swipe to the top of the list and only then, swipe to close the sheet).

I've tried to do it by changing physics and stuff (on existing sheet packages such as rubber), but I wasn't able to achieve that smoothness.

Here's a GIF showing the behaviour I want:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe a `showModalBottomSheet()` with a `GestureDetector` will look similar

Comment: Lack of smoothness may be due to running in debug mode.